# Problem redirecting to file from post link

Tags: django

I am having trouble with redirecting the link to the proper file when a link inside the post is clicked. The file is stored in a media and can be viewed from localhost/media/filename.pdf with no issues.

**Inside of post_detail.html**

```
<a href="/media/{{ object.post_files }}">{{ object.post_files }}</a>
```

**My urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostList.as_view(), name='forum-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='forum-about'),
    path('post/new/', PostCreate.as_view(), name='post-create'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', PostDetail.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/update/', PostUpdate.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/delete/', PostDelete.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('post/comment/', CommentCreate.as_view(), name='add_comment_to_post'),  
]
```

I'm assuming this is a path error because the error is:http://localhost:8000/post/4/media/filename.pdf

This would mean it is checking staying with in post.

Comment: Are you sure there is a slash (`/`) in front of `media`? Anyway, usually it is not a good idea to make URLs yourself. You probably can use `{{ object.post_files.url }}` instead.

Comment: fixed! thanks you for your help.